# How to properly add image to tab in TabControls using WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to have images instead of text in tabs for my TabControl, so I have done this:

- added image in ImageList
- myTabControl.ImageList is pointing to this ImageList
- TabPage.ImageIndex has an index to that image

And this is the result:

[image: Image in tab]

As you can see, the image is all blurry.

If I modify TabPage.BackgroundImage to point to this image, then the image looks fine as shown here:

[image: Image as Background in TabPage]

Is there a way to make the image in tab look that good?

Comment: Show your code, it seems that you have wrong size of image

Comment: Ok, i understand you, wait a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In default your imagelist contain image 16x16 you should to change size to your image. after it, image will be norm

**EDIT**

to know the size of the image, you should open property of image file, in tab 'additional' you can find Sizes, this sizes must be on your Imagelist property ImageSize